Unnest list column: In row 2, can't recycle input of size 2 to size 4
I'm encountering issues when attempting to unnest a dataframe containing list columns. The dataframe structure and the unnesting code I'm using are as follows:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = structure(list(num_dos = c(41713200L, 41735799L, 41740459L, 41819734L
    ), `DAT_SD_29 ` = list("08/07/2024 15:41", c("11/07/2024 13:16", 
    "09/08/2024 14:17"), "16/07/2024 13:21", "01/08/2024 17:06"), 
        `DAT_SD_99 ` = list(c("09/07/2024 05:09", "09/07/2024 22:58"
        ), c("29/07/2024 16:35", "12/07/2024 05:09", "12/07/2024 22:56", 
        "23/08/2024 08:22"), c("05/08/2024 15:34", "10/07/2024 10:40", 
        "20/07/2024 12:22", "10/08/2024 10:18"), "26/07/2024 11:50")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df |> tidyr::unnest()

Previously, this code worked as expected, but now it's producing unexpected results. I'm getting the following error:
Error in `unnest()`:
! In row 2, can't recycle input of size 2 to size 4.


Please read the text of the [tag:tidy] tag you have included on your question. Good luck.

As the error states, the issue arises due to the varying list lengths between the two list columns. To return your desired result, unnest_longer() twice:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  unnest_longer(`DAT_SD_29 `) |> 
  unnest_longer(`DAT_SD_99 `)

# # A tibble: 15 × 3
#     num_dos `DAT_SD_29 `     `DAT_SD_99 `    
#       <int> <chr>            <chr>           
#  1 41713200 08/07/2024 15:41 09/07/2024 05:09
#  2 41713200 08/07/2024 15:41 09/07/2024 22:58
#  3 41735799 11/07/2024 13:16 29/07/2024 16:35
#  4 41735799 11/07/2024 13:16 12/07/2024 05:09
#  5 41735799 11/07/2024 13:16 12/07/2024 22:56
#  6 41735799 11/07/2024 13:16 23/08/2024 08:22
#  7 41735799 09/08/2024 14:17 29/07/2024 16:35
#  8 41735799 09/08/2024 14:17 12/07/2024 05:09
#  9 41735799 09/08/2024 14:17 12/07/2024 22:56
# 10 41735799 09/08/2024 14:17 23/08/2024 08:22
# 11 41740459 16/07/2024 13:21 05/08/2024 15:34
# 12 41740459 16/07/2024 13:21 10/07/2024 10:40
# 13 41740459 16/07/2024 13:21 20/07/2024 12:22
# 14 41740459 16/07/2024 13:21 10/08/2024 10:18
# 15 41819734 01/08/2024 17:06 26/07/2024 11:50

Based on the OP's comment, if you have many list columns, or the list columns were named dynamically e.g. you don't know the names of the columns beforehand, use:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df |>
  select(where(is.list)) |>
  names() |>
  reduce(~ unnest_longer(.x, all_of(.y)), .init = df)


Adding this should also help by using a function:
Identify columns that are lists
list_columns = res |>
select(where(is.list)) |>
names()
Unnest all list columns using reduce
res_unnested = reduce(list_columns, function(data, col) {
unnest_longer(data, col)
}, .init = res)

@Mostafa90 - Supplying a vector of names directly to select() has been deprecated, you now need to include either all_of() or any_of(). In your example, use unnest_longer(data, all_of(col)). I have updated the answer to include a more generalised solution.
